# Hyperscript unable to find element in DOM

Tags: htmx, hyperscript

I am trying to run the following code using hyperscript based on HTMX HX-Trigger tags as part of response.

```
<script type="text/hyperscript">
            on membershipsChanged
              log "memberships"
              remove .hidden from #alert-success
              wait 10s
              add .hidden to #alert-success
            end
 </script>
```

The HTML it is amending is

```
<div
            id="alert-success"
            class="hidden p-4 mb-4 text-sm text-yellow-800 rounded-lg bg-yellow-50 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-yellow-300"
            role="alert"
          >
            <span class="font-medium">Memberships updated successfully</span>
</div>
```

It is giving me error that `#alert-success' is null`. I have attempted to place `<script>` at different places such as above the element or beneath the element to see that it might pick the `<div>` with `id="alert-success"` but nothing is working though log provided using `log "memberships"` is visible in the consol.

Comment: Can you provide the element where you're triggering this event from?

Comment: Actually I am triggering the script provided using response sent from backend (having HTMX HX-Trigger response element). It triggers membershipsChanged function on client side and it is happening smoothly till this stage as I can see Log "membership" in the console and then hyperscript throws error #alert-success' is null. I am not sure why this #alert-success Hyperscript not able to pick as it is already part of DOM.